# Display the results in the HTML

Tags: php, html

I am working on my code to fetch the data to output them in the HTML. I have got a problem with display the data in the html source outside of the PHP because I have received an error:

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/username/public_html/check_score.php on line 150**

Here is the line 150:

```
foreach($score->rules AS $rule) {
   echo '<div name="test-row" style="margin-top:-1px">
   <div name="description" style="float: left; width:470px;">' . $rule->description . '</div>';

   echo '<div name="scores" style="float: right">' . $rule->score . '</div>';
   echo '</div><br><hr>';
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn1']))
{
    sleep(1);
    $ch = curl_init('http://example.com/check_score');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $message = "hey chris";
    $header = "Delivered-To: example@gmail.com
    Received: by 2002:a0c:938a:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id f10csp5715121qvf;
      Sun, 2 Dec 2018 06:07:45 -0800 (PST)
    the long list of the header goes here...

    Hey rob,

    How you doing?";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('email' => $header, 'options'=>'long')));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $score = json_decode($response);

    ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
          });
      </script>
      <?php
}   
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button name="btn1" id="btn1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block button-size">Check for score
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" style="height:600px;">
            <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">SpamScore</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 77%;"> 
              <?php
                    echo '<p><b>SpamScore points: <span id="bbb"></span>' . $score->score . '</b></p><hr>';

                    foreach($score->rules AS $rule) { 
                        echo '<div name="test-row" style="margin-top:-1px">
                        <div name="description" style="float: left; width:470px;">' . $rule->description . '</div>';
                        echo '<div name="scores" style="float: right">' . $rule->score . '</div>';
                        echo '</div><br><hr>';
                    }
            ?>
            </div><br>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

I have checked the results for the $score in the PHP which it show:

```
stdClass Object ( [success] => 1 [score] => 0.2 [rules] => Array ( [0] => 
stdClass Object ( [score] => 0.1 [description] => Message has a DKIM or DK 
signature, not necessarily valid ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [score] => 0.1 
[description] => DKIM or DK signature exists, but is not valid ) ) [report] 
=> pts rule description ---- ---------------------- ------------------------
-------------------------- 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK 
signature, not necessarily valid 0.1 DKIM_INVALID DKIM or DK signature 
exists, but is not valid )
```

When I have put the $score in the HTML, the results will show as empty.

It was working fine yesterday but today here it is not working. I dont really understand why the variable `$score` show as empty in the HTML when I can be able to fetch the data in PHP with no problem. I tried to find the answer on google but I can't find it anywhere.

Can you please help me with how I can be able to display the data in the HTML using the variable `$score`?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, right now you are definitively successfully retrieving the decoded JSON from your cURL request?

Comment: @Ryan Yes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed something here. I'm not sure if it'll fix the error, but it may be a starting point. The first echoed line within your loop doesn't have a trailing semicolon:

```
foreach($score->rules AS $rule) { 
    echo '<div name="test-row" style="margin-top:-1px">
    <div name="description" style="float: left; width:470px;">' . $rule->description . '</div>';
    echo '<div name="scores" style="float: right">' . $rule->score . '</div>';
    echo '</div><br><hr>';
}
```

Give this a shot:

```
foreach($score->rules AS $rule) { 
    echo '<div name="test-row" style="margin-top:-1px">;
    <div name="description" style="float: left; width:470px;">' . $rule->description . '</div>';
    echo '<div name="scores" style="float: right">' . $rule->score . '</div>';
    echo '</div><br><hr>';
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, but it have got nothing to do with missing semicolon because I am using `echo '<div name="test-row" style="margin-top:-1px">` that come with the same line as `<div name="description" style="float: left; width:470px;">' . $rule->description . '</div>';` as you can see it.

Comment: I have tried to use `echo $rule->description;` and i still get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Ah, misread that line. Sorry about that. What do you get when you echo this within your loop: echo '<pre>';var_dump($rule);echo '</pre>';?

Comment: When I try `echo '<pre>';var_dump($rule);echo '</pre>';` before the loop it show as NULL. And when I try in the loop it show as empty. Any idea?

Comment: It'll always be NULL if you try to access $rule outside the loop, as it's not accessible outside the loop. Try changing the $rule to $scope->rules in your var_dump declaration inside the loop, and report back what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$score` variable fill on form submit, So you can't allow to `$score` variable after form post in the modal view.

Can you try following code instead of your codes,

***UPDATED***

*My answer is changed for correct solution.*

curl.php;

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['submit'])
    {
        sleep(1);
        $ch = curl_init('http://example.com/check_score');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $message = "hey chris";
        $header = "Delivered-To: example@gmail.com
        Received: by 2002:a0c:938a:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id f10csp5715121qvf;
          Sun, 2 Dec 2018 06:07:45 -0800 (PST)
        the long list of the header goes here...

        Hey rob,

        How you doing?";

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('email' => $header, 'options'=>'long')));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
    } else {
        $response = json_encode(array('success' => false));
    }
    echo $response;
    exit;
?>
```

form.html;

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button name="btn1" id="btn1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block button-size">Check for score
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(0);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'curl.php',
        data: {
          submit: true
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.modal-body').html('');
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            if(data.success){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                $('.modal-body').append('<p><b>SpamScore points: <span id="bbb"></span>' + data.score + '</b></p><hr>'); 
                $.each(data.rules, function(key, value){
                    $('.modal-body').append('<div name="test-row" style="margin-top:-1px"><div name="description" style="float: left; width:470px;">' + value.description + '</div><div name="scores" style="float: right">' + value.score + '</div></div><br><hr>');
                });
            }
        },
        type: 'POST'
    });
});
</script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" style="height:600px;">
            <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">SpamScore</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 77%;"></div><br>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

I do not able to test above codes, but it's must be work.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but when I click on a submit button the modal did not show so it will only work outside of PHP just before the `<form action="" method="post">`. Any idea?

Comment: I think you did just copy, past and run it. Did you think fix codes any? Yes it did not work because had is a few typo on it. Why didn't think fixed them. I fixed on the html form and it works.